# difference between generic serial bulk in/out driver and generic usb serial driver?

Tags: usb

Is generic serial bulk in/out driver same as generic USB serial driver?

Comment: Could you edit your question with specific use requirement?

Answer (score 1):

> Is generic serial bulk in/out driver same as generic USB serial driver?

No.

"bulk in/out" describes one of the three transfer types of USB (the other being isochronous and "interrupt").

Not quite sure what is meant with that, but it's *not a device driver*; it just describes the basic communication method over USB you're supposed to use.

When someone says "USB serial driver", they usual mean the driver for a device that offers a UART-style serial port (like, a USB-to-UART converter, a modem, or something similar). Typically, these devices belong in the USB CDC class, and there's a Linux driver for these that just give you a /dev/ttyUSBn.

> I need to "use generic serial bulk in/out driver" to configure USB in linux environment.

That is very cryptic. I think you're giving us a bit of a strange interpretation of vague documentation you're having – not your fault, but we can't advise much on it like this. We'd need way more context.

Comment: says *who*? I mean, you're just stringing together words, and they don't seem to make sense to you, and honestly, they don't make sense to me either. Because, no, that's simply not true. Please, give way more context.

Comment: OK, this info is very critical and should've been part of your question right from the beginning!

Comment: @KA search for "gadget" if you want OTG. It's quite easy -- you don't need to write drivers.